# Amicable numbers function gives the wrong result

Tags: c, numbers

As [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21) link describes I have to create a code for computing the sum of all amicable numbers in the range.. The code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int SumProperDivisors(int Number);

int main(void) {
    //a != b , if d(b) = a ve d(a) = b
    int DividedSum = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(index = 1; index<10000; index++)
    {
        DividedSum = SumProperDivisors(index); //a
        temp=SumProperDivisors(DividedSum);   //b
        if(DividedSum!=temp)
        {
            if(SumProperDivisors(temp)==DividedSum&&SumProperDivisors(DividedSum)==temp)
            {
            //  printf("%d ",index);
                sum +=index;
                printf("%d ",sum);
            }

        }

    }
    printf("\n\n%d",sum);


    return 0;
}


int SumProperDivisors(int Number)
{
    int index;
    int sum = 0;
    for(index = 1; index < Number; ++index)
    {
        if((Number%index)==0)
        {
            sum += index;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Produces the wrong result of `63968` while the correct result should be `31626`. I am asking this in the name of a friend.
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a comment, please find a better name than `DividedByZero()`.

Comment: I agree. If the code was mine.. I would name it  differently.

Comment: No offence, still you're the poster here, so, if you please ...

Comment: Suggest a name then.

Comment: If you know the correct result surely then you have some other working code...

Comment: And also a problem in mine.. This is for educational purposes.. it will be considered cheating to copy/paste codes.

Comment: @WeatherVane The first few amicable numbers are listed at [A063990 Amicable numbers](http://oeis.org/A063990) so it is easy to verify the sum for the desired code should be 31626.

Comment: A list of amicable numbers does not even make sense. Amicable numbers come in *pairs*.

Comment: @WeatherVane An excellent point. Fortunately, for checking the desired sum, "The first time a pair is not adjacent is x = 67095, y = 71145" (from my earlier link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have found (220, 284) you need to record that you have already found 284, otherwise when the loop iterates to 284 it will find 220 again.

Crudely, with no thought given to optimisation, and in VB:

```
Sub ListAmicablePairs()
    Dim alreadyFound As New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 1 To 9999
        Dim spd1 = SumProperDivisors(i)
        Dim spd2 = SumProperDivisors(spd1)
        If spd2 = i AndAlso spd1 <> i AndAlso Not alreadyFound.Contains(i) Then
            alreadyFound.Add(i)
            alreadyFound.Add(spd1)
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", i, spd1)
        End If
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(alreadyFound.Sum())

End Sub
```

Outputs:

> (220, 284)
>   (1184, 1210)
>   (2620, 2924)
>   (5020, 5564)
>   (6232, 6368)
>   31626